# Unable to start tomcat7 with webapp (spring + hibernate + hibernate search 4.5) NoClassDefFound : CorruptIndexException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-search

I am trying to start my tomcat 7. It throws

```
ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] (ContextLoader.java:307) - Context initialization failed
```

Code:

```
Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in
ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/hibernate-config.xml]: Invocation of
init method failed; nested exception is
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError:
org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator: Provider
org.hibernate.search.hcore.impl.HibernateSearchIntegrator could not be
instantiated: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
org/apache/lucene/index/CorruptIndexException


Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
org.apache.lucene.index.CorruptIndexException   at
java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)  at
java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)  at
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  at
java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)  at
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)   at
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
```

Comment: are you using maven ? if yes plz post your dependencies section related to hibernate (including hibernate search)

Comment: I am not using maven for dependencies.

Comment: the jars you are using are not compatible. You need to use Hibernate Search + ORM + Lucene (+ supporting libraries) in their right versions. Either verify via a Maven POM which versions you need or use one of the SourceForge release bundles. They contain the right versions as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing org.apache.lucene.index.CorruptIndexException   dependencies .. Check the required jars are in class path.

Comment: I just updated the classpath. Now it throws below exception..Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: class org.hibernate.search.util.impl.DelegateNamedAnalyzer overrides final method tokenStream.(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/io/Reader;)Lorg/apache/lucene/analysis/TokenStream;